# GCC 6.4.0 Error with VMWare player and Kali linux

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to install VMWare player on Kali. I have the bundles downloaded and installed. Everything it updated, etc, and I have run these commands. `sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, `sudo apt get install open-vm-tools`

but I keep getting a VMware Kernel Module Updater. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXeV1.png)

I browse and find a gcc-6 under /usr/bin/ and select to install it, it asks for a password, type in my root password and such, but then it just exits.

I do have gcc-6.4.0 installed.

```
~$ whereis gcc-6
gcc-6: /usr/bin/gcc-6

~$ gcc-6 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-6
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 6.4.0-4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.4.0 20170820 (Debian 6.4.0-4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.  Here is how I got around it:

1. Run vmplayer as root.
2. Enter /usr/bin/gcc-6 as gcc location
3. Wait. Exit vmplayer
4. Run vmplayer as normal user

Answer (score -1):

Run vmware the first time with sudo work for me.